# How to create a single list from rows of lists?

Tags: python, list, dataframe, rows

I have a dataframe where one of my columns includes rows of lists.

Each individual row in my column is a list of elements.

I want to create ONE list that includes all the values from each row.

I have tried

```
final_list = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(mylist))
```

but this keeps each row has a list.

The total length of all of my rows is `1981`. 
When I check for final_list it still has a length of `1981` which is wrong because each row has multiple elements in the lists.

I expect for the length of my final_list to have each row's list elements.

Comment: can you create a [mcve] for the same please? It makes it easier for people to help you. Also take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) for some guidelines.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a flat list out of list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using ***pandas.DataFrame*** (marked as df in code), you can work it out using ***pandas.DataFrame.values.tolist()***:

```
final_list = [item for sublist in df.values.tolist() for item in sublist]
```

Methodology of this list operation is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists).